# Why does a segmentation fault happen when i declare an integer pointer p and assign it to the return value of my function?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, gcc, segmentation-fault

My function also returns an integer pointer. I was under the impression that array names are just integer pointers, so that's why i declared it like that. I have made a function called reverse() to reverse a pointer and when i run it on my ubuntu 18.04 with gcc version 7.5, I get a segmentation fault core dumped. Why is this and what is the correct and most efficient code for this?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int * reverse(int * array, int n){
    int * rev;
    int i = n - 1;
    int j = 0;
    while(i >= 0){
        rev[j] = array[i];
        j++;
        i--;
    }
    return rev;
}

int main(){
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int * p; //the pointer p that im declaring
    p = reverse(array, 4); //i think this is the segmentation error
    int i = 0;
    printf("the first element is %d", p[0]);
}
```

Comment: `int * rev;  rev[j] = array[i];` is undefined behaviour because `rev` is an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: Activate compiler warnings. Use `-Wall -Wextra` and they would have explained the problem

Comment: oh yes thanks a lot guys!

Comment: BTW the most efficient way to find out what happens in such cases is to use your debugger. Learn how to use it, it will save you countless hours.

Comment: "_ I was under the impression that array names are just integer pointers_" That impression is wrong. Array names _decay_ to pointers in some cases, like when passed to a function, but they are very different things. Array names have size info, whereas pointers lose them. Also, of course if the elements were another type, it won't be `int[]` or `int*`.

Comment: Just single-step through the program using your favourite debugger? They aren't hard to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I have made a function called reverse() to reverse a pointer and when i run it on my ubuntu 18.04 with gcc version 7.5, I get a segmentation fault core dumped. Why is this?"

The pointer `rev` in `reverse` does not point to any memory. You need to allocate memory of `n * sizeof(int)` and assign `rev` to point there before dereferencing `rev`. Else you got undefined behavior accessing unallocated memory.

```
int * rev = malloc( n * sizeof(int) );
if (!rev)
{
     perror("malloc");
     // error routine.
}
```